# How to use threads to get input from keyboard in python 3?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x

I am making a snake game which requires the player to press the `WASD` keys without stopping the game process to to get input from player. So I can't use `input()` for this situation because then the game stops ticking to get input.

I found a `getch()` function which immediately gives input without pressing enter, but this function also stops game ticking to get input like `input()`. I decided to use threading module to get input via `getch()` in different thread. The problem is that getch() isn't working while in different thread and I'm not sure why.

```
import threading, time
from msvcrt import getch

key = "lol" #it never changes because getch() in thread1 is useless

def thread1():
    while True:
        key = getch() #this simply is almost ignored by interpreter, the only thing it
        #gives is that delays print() unless you press any key
        print("this is thread1()")

threading.Thread(target = thread1).start()

while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    print(key)
```

So why `getch()` is useless when it is in `thread1()`?

Comment: You may want to consider installing and using pygame instead of using threads. It has functions that lets you easily know which key is being pressed on the keyboard so you don't have to muck around with threads.

Comment: Why use threads in this example anyway? No need for it. Use a normal run-loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was that you're creating a local variable `key` inside `thread1` instead of overwriting the existing one. The quick-and-easy solution would be to declare `key` to be global inside `thread1`.

Finally, you should consider using locks. I don't know if it's necessary or not, but I'd imagine weird things could happen if you try and write a value to `key` in the thread while printing it out at the same time.

The working code:

```
import threading, time
from msvcrt import getch

key = "lol"

def thread1():
    global key
    lock = threading.Lock()
    while True:
        with lock:
            key = getch()

threading.Thread(target = thread1).start()

while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    print(key)
```

Comment: Not working because thread1() is not repeating like you said.
I tried to "while True:" everything in thread1() and it started to work perfectly. And I dont even know what is threading.Lock()

Comment: @foxneSs: Ah, you're right about the 'while True:' -- my bad. I edited my answer. `threading.Lock` will make sure that only the thread is allowed to modify the 'key' variable when the lock is active. More information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393073/why-should-you-lock-threads

Answer (score 0):

I tried using getch but it didn't work for me... (win7 here).

You can try using tkinter module // but I still can't make it running with threads

```
# Respond to a key without the need to press enter
import tkinter as tk    #on python 2.x use "import Tkinter as tk"

def keypress(event):
    if event.keysym == 'Escape':
        root.destroy()
    x = event.char
    if x == "w":
        print ("W pressed")
    elif x == "a":
        print ("A pressed")
    elif x == "s":
        print ("S pressed")
    elif x == "d":
        print ("D pressed")
    else:
        print (x)

root = tk.Tk()
print ("Press a key (Escape key to exit):")
root.bind_all('<Key>', keypress)
# don't show the tk window
root.withdraw()
root.mainloop()
```

As Michael0x2a says you may try using library made for game-making - pygame or pyglet.

@EDIT @Michael0x2a:
Are you sure your code works?
Whatever I press it always prints the same key.

@EDIT2:
Thanks!

Comment: For whatever reason, getch appears to work only from the command line. It doesn't appear to work if you run the file inside IDLE.