# Real-time capture and processing of keypresses (e.g. keypress event)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multithreading

*Note: I want to do this without using any external packages, like PyGame, etc.*

I am attempting to capture individual keypresses as they arrive and perform an action for specific characters, whether I simply want to "re-echo" the character, or not display it at all and do something else.

I have found a cross-platform (though not sure about OS X) getch() implementation because I do not want to read a whole line like input() does:

```
# http://code.activestate.com/recipes/134892/
def getch():
    try:
        import termios
    except ImportError:
        # Non-POSIX. Return msvcrt's (Windows') getch.
        import msvcrt
        return msvcrt.getch

    # POSIX system. Create and return a getch that manipulates the tty.
    fd = sys.stdin.fileno()
    old_settings = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
    try:
        tty.setraw(fd)
        ch = sys.stdin.read(1)
    finally:
        termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSADRAIN, old_settings)
    return ch
```

**[Attempt 1]** 
I first tried a simple while-true loop to poll getch, but if I type too fast, characters go missing. Reducing the sleep time makes it worse. The debug statements only print on press of the enter key and not consistently in time nor position. (It appears there might be some line buffering going on?) Taking out the loop and sleep lets it work once but perfectly.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
import tty
import time


def main():
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        sys.stdout.write(" DEBUG:Before ")
        sys.stdout.write(getch())
        sys.stdout.write(" DEBUG:After ")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**[Attempt 2]** 
I got an example for using a threaded approach (https://stackoverflow.com/a/14043979/2752206) but it "locks up" and won't accept any input (including `Ctrl-C`, and etc)..

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
import tty
import time
import threading

key = 'Z'


def main():
    threading.Thread(target=getchThread).start()

    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        sys.stdout.write(" DEBUG:Before ")
        sys.stdout.write(key)
        sys.stdout.write(" DEBUG:After ")


def getchThread():
    global key
    lock = threading.Lock()
    while True:
        with lock:
            key = getch()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Does anyone have any advice or guidance? Or more importantly, can someone explain *why* the two attempts do not work? Thanks.

Comment: You return the function `msvcrt.getch`, but not the result of it being called.

Comment: Thanks for the catch. I modified a code snippet, but I'm on Linux. =P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, I don't really thing you need multithreading. You'd need that if you, for example, wanted to do some tasks like drawing on screen or whatever and capturing keys while you do this.

Let's consider a case where you only want to capture keys and after each keypress execute some action: Exit, if **x** was pressed, otherwise just print the character. All you need for this case is simple while loop

```
def process(key):
    if key == 'x':
        exit('exitting')
    else:
        print(key, end="", flush=True)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:
        key = getch()
        process(key)
```

Notice absence of sleep(). I am assuming you thought getch() won't wait for user input so you set 1s sleep time. However, your getch() waits for one entry and then returns it. In this case, global variable is not really useful, so you might as well just call process(getch()) inside the loop.

`print(key, end="", flush=True)` => the extra arguments will ensure pressed keys stay on one line, not appending newline character every time you print something.

The other case, where you'd want to execute different stuff simultaneously, should use threading.

Consider this code:

```
n = 0
quit = False

def process(key):
    if key == 'x':
        global quit
        quit = True
        exit('exitting')
    elif key == 'n':
        global n
        print(n)
    else:
        print(key, end="", flush=True)

def key_capturing():
    while True:
        process(getch())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    threading.Thread(target=key_capturing).start()
    while not quit:
        n += 1
        time.sleep(0.1)
```

This will create global variable `n` and increment it 10 times a second in main thread. Simultaneously, `key_capturing` method listens to keys pressed and does the same thing as in previous example + when you press **n** on your keyboard, current value of the global variable `n` will be printed.

Closing note: as @zondo noted, you really missed braces in the getch() definition. `return msvcrt.getch` should most likely be `return msvcrt.getch()`

Comment: Thanks! This was a great explanation. The other 'solutions' on and off of StackExchange were using sleep and/or threads, but this is simple like it should be. I do plan to do drawing while taking input so thanks also for the threaded explanation.

One issue though, pressing x in the threaded example doesn't exit and just stalls.

Comment: @RobAlexander it will stop the separate thread, not the main one. You'll need to send SIGINT (ctrl+c) after pressing x to kill the main thread as well

Comment: Thanks. Last question I have, not sure if I need to start a new question though. But any suggestions for letting getch() not capture ASCII codes below 32, i.e. ctrl&command codes? Or "rethrowing" the key in some way, in order to allow ctrl-z, and other terminal commands?

Comment: @RobAlexander Well, you can add to process(key) as first line: `if ord(key)<32: return` but I don't think their function will still work. I'd suggest creating new thread for that.