# How to do computing until s is pressed?

Tags: python-3.x

How can I do a computing program in Python 3 such that it does computing while program is running, shows the computing status when one presses s and quits the program when one presses ctrl+c? I know I can use try-catch but how can I read when user presses s? I know input but it stops the computing when waits the key press. I'm using Ubuntu 17.04 on bash command line.

I tried

```
n = 0
try:
    while True:
        n += 1
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Stopping")
```

Comment: You could look at answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/35384301/131187 and similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are on Linux you can use the [`curses`](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/curses.html) module to do that.
The way `curses` works is simple. We set `curses` to "monitor" the `compute()` function (the `keypress` variable works as an event handler and you can call it as you wish - I chose to call it *keypress*).

As you can also read in the documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/curses.html#user-input), the most common way to get input to a window is to use its `getch()` method, but `getch()` pauses and waits for the user to hit a key. To change this behavior we use the method `nodelay(1)`. By using `nodelay(1)`, `getch()` for the window becomes *non-blocking* and returns `curses.ERR` (a value of **-1**) when no input is ready.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
import curses

def compute(keypress):
    keypress.nodelay(1)
    n = 0
    try:
        while True:
            n += 1
            key = keypress.getch()
            if key != -1 and key==115: # ord('s')=115
                keypress.addstr(str(n) +'\n')
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        sys.exit(0)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    curses.wrapper(compute)
```