# initialize python module attribute when accessed the first time and ensure atomicity

Tags: python-3.x, python-module

is there a way I can delay the initialization of module attribute to when it's first accessed? Also how can I ensure there's only one copy of the instance got created? I use if-statement in the get_client() example to do this. But this could still have chance to create multiple instance when called by multiple threads. Any better idea? Thanks.

a_module.py

```python
client = None

def get_client():
    global client
    if client is None:
        client = EmailEndpoint()
    return client
```

when I use a_module.py, I'm expecting:

```python
import a_module  # does not initialize 'a_module.client'

print(a_module.get_client())  # initialize 'a_module.client'
```

Comment: Take a look at this thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393073/why-should-you-lock-threads)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks progmatico for the hint. I'll answer my own question. This is my updated code with thread lock to guarantee only one copy of the 'MyObject' instance gets created even the method is called concurrently. And '_client' will only initialize when it's retrieved the first time.

```
lock = Lock()
_client = None

def get_client():
    with lock:
        global _client
        if _client is None:
            _client = MyObject()
        return _client
```